# Force a class implementing interface A to also inherit from a type derived from interface B

Tags: c#, inheritance

what I want is that if class A implements my interface (B) I also want A being forced to implement an interface/type derived from type C.

In code, the result would look like this:

```
public interface SomeInterface
{
    // implementing this interface forces the implementing class to also implement
    // a derived interface/type of SomeBaseInterface 
    void SomeMethod();
}

public interface SomeBaseInterface
{
    void SomeBaseMethod();
}

public interface SomeOtherInterface : SomeBaseInterface
{
    void SomeOtherMethod();
}

public class ImplementingClass : SomeInterface, SomeOtherInterface // <- if not
 // implementing an interface/type derived from SomeBaseInterface
 // this should not compile
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
    }

    public void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
    }

    public void SomeBaseMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

*edit
<strike>it would also work to 'mark' `SomeBaseInterface` as not inheritable by a class. Meaning that only another interface/abstract class can inherit from it.</strike> not possible, see [C# Interfaces- only implement an interface in other interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283432/c-sharp-interfaces-only-implement-an-interface-in-other-interfaces)

Comment: It looks a bit like you're going to end up with the sort of hierarchy spelt out in Eric Lippert's [Curiouser and Curiouser post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx). Note the bold warning towards the end.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't derive SomeInterface from SomeBaseInterface? It's only compile-time way to force to implement both.

Comment: @Adriano yeah, just clarified. ImplementingClass needs to implement a type derived from SomeBaseInterface. Not SomeBaseInterface directly.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that's interesting but there is one thing missing: What I would want is something like `class Cat : Animal<Feline>` and `Cat` then being forced to implement `Feline`

Comment: What's wrong with having `Feline: Animal` and then `Cat: Feline`?

Comment: @SergeyKrusch there is nothing 'forcing' Cat to implement Feline instead of Animal.

Comment: Really? Cat is forced to implement both interfaces this way (namely Animal and Feline).

Comment: @SergeyKrusch I think I lost track somewhere...could you hack up some mock up code?  Because I'm not seeing how Cat is forced to implement Animal *and* Feline.

Comment: See my answer. It is not, exactly, an answer to your question. But I think you are trying to do something, that you will regret of later.

Comment: @SergeyKrusch * that you will regret of later.* add it to the list ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can force the use of one interface when using another, unless you derive one interface from the other.  However, you could use attributes and set up a unit test that would check your code for you.

```
[MyInterfaceCheck(typeof(IMyBaseInterface))]
public interface IMyInterfaceA {...}

public interface IMyBaseInterface {...}

public interface IMyInterfaceB : IMyBaseInterface {...}

public class MyClass : IMyInterfaceA, IMyInterfaceB {...}
```

The attribute would be defined simply as:

```
public class MyInterfaceCheckAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyInterfaceCheckAttribute(Type typeThatShouldAlsoBeInherited)
    {
        if (!typeThatShouldAlsoBeInherited.IsInterface)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Incorrect type being used with MyInterfaceCheckAttribute.");
        }
        TypeThatShouldBeInherited = typeThatShouldAlsoBeInherited;
    }

    public Type TypeThatShouldBeInherited { get; private set; }
}
```

And the Unit Test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CheckInterfaceInheritenceTest()
{
    Dictionary<Type, MyInterfaceCheckAttribute> typesToCheck = new Dictionary<Type, MyInterfaceCheckAttribute>();
    foreach (Type typeToCheck in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
    {
        MyInterfaceCheckAttribute myAtt = typeToCheck.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(MyInterfaceCheckAttribute), true) as MyInterfaceCheckAttribute;
        if (myAtt != null)
        {
            typesToCheck.Add(typeToCheck, myAtt);
        }
    }

    foreach (Type typeToCheck in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
    {
        Type[] interfaces = typeToCheck.GetInterfaces();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, MyInterfaceCheckAttribute> kvp in typesToCheck)
        {
            if (interfaces.Contains(kvp.Key) && !interfaces.Contains(kvp.Value.TypeThatShouldBeInherited))
            {
                Assert.Fail("The type " + typeToCheck.Name + " should inherit the interface " + kvp.Value.TypeThatShouldBeInherited.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way would be to have `SomeInterface : SomeBaseInterface` and have `ImplementingClass : SomeInterface, SomeOtherInterface`. Can you clarify why it is not a possibility? This forces the class implementing `SomeInterface` to at least inherit from `SomeBaseInterface` and this can be extended by additionally by inheriting from `SomeOtherInterface`.

The only difference is that it's possible to no inherit `SomeOtherInterface`, but for all you know that interface could contain nothing anyway.

`EmptyInterface`:

```
interface SomeOtherOtherInterface : SomeBaseInterface {
}
```

I would suggest if your wanting to allow the class to inherit from the above interface and not `SomeBaseInterface` you're doing something wrong. Also the implication is that your specifying for the existence of more unknown methods, which also is a touch suspicious.

Is it that there are things you should have put in `SomeBaseInterface` but didn't? Is there, for example, a `void SendEmail` in one derived interface and a `void SendFax` in another when clearly something like `SendMessage` should have been in `SomeBaseInterface` all along?

But obviously, if you want to proceed anyway use the unit testing approach.

Comment: uhm. I've a BaseInterface from which most 'modules' (MEF) are inheriting. It forces all modules to have a config, a name...stuff like that. Now, I've different kinds of modules. Some are, for example, UserInterfaces. Some are for pushing informations into a database, some just 'do stuff'. I grouped all those modules. Meaning that for each group (database, UI...) there is one 'Parent' module managing the 'child' modules. Each module group has one interface defining it and that is derived from the Base interface. Each parent should implement the Parent interface and a group interface.

Comment: Right, right. It may be something you can't enforce then, after all hypothetically speaking its not your responsibility to make sure derived classes make sense. But have you considered the possibility someone may make `ImplementingClass` abstract and inherited by both your database and UI classes? I think maybe just comment in what the class is for and if someone wants to make a class that uses `SomeInterface` but doesn't usefully interact with any of your systems, let them or unit test against it (as per the accepted answer).

Comment: I already wrote a comment in there ;). I also figured out how to make comments visible inside another project (pesky xml files). So that's covered ;).

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear about inheritance and interfaces. Let's assume that we have interfaces `IAnimal` and `IFeline`:

```
interface IAnimal
{
    void Eat();
}

interface IFeline: IAnimal
{
    void Purr();
}
```

Now let's define class `Cat` and require it to implement interface `IFeline`:

```
class Cat: IFeline
{

}
```

Compiling the code:

```
'Cat' does not implement interface member 'IFeline.Purr()'
'Cat' does not implement interface member 'IAnimal.Eat()'
```

And now it is clear that compiler expects us to implement both interfaces `IAnimal` and `IFeline` in class `Cat`.

Comment: correct. But there is nothing preventing Cat from just implementing IAnimal.

Comment: Do you mean, nothing is preventing from writing `class Cat: IAnimal`?

Comment: correct. See the striked text in my question for further detail.

Comment: Hm... I see. But why do you want this? What will happen if someone will have, let's say `Wombat: IAnimal`?

Comment: well, that'd mean that a Wombat is just an animal. It has the generic functions of an animal but it actually can't do anything aside from that. So it won't be a Wombat. For example all `Feline`s have the ability to Hunt and use scratch posts and they are able to use their retractable claws. A Wombat derived from IAnimal on the other hand wouldn't be able to dig/build their tunnelsystems or 'crush' a foe against the roof of their tunnel. Sidenote: You just made me explain to my boss why I was reading a wikipedia article about wombats...that's a new one ;)

Comment: :D
Well, actually, it is you, who decide what `Wombat` can do. And it doesn't really matters whether you write `class Wombat: IAnimal` or `class Wombat: IVombatidae` (with defining `interface IVombatidae: IAnimal`) until you actually have some code that knows about `IVombatidae`.

Comment: Don't you want to break Liskov substitution principle? I.e. you expect `IAnimal` to do something that isn't explicitly stated in the interface (which is bad).

Comment: not really. I want to define that an Animal has to be a specific Animal inside the Animal interface. Also all my modules are only 'interacting' with eachother via those interfaces. So if it's not defined in an interface, it doesn't exist.